# function set table name as parameter and get columns name and table name from XML file in sqlcommand c#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm trying to use variable that contains column name and another variable that contains table name from xml file  in c# but I get this error :

**Incorrect syntax for '@req'**

my function set table name and file xml as parameter and get columns name and table name from XML file in select sqlcommand c#:

```
 public void readFileXML(string tableMapping, string file)
 {
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);

    foreach (XElement ELParent in doc.Root.Elements())
    {
       if (ELParent.Attribute("sql_name").Value == tableMapping)
    {

        foreach (XElement ElChild in ELParent.Elements())
        {
             cnSQL = new SqlConnection(string_Sql);
             cnSQL.Open();

              string table = ELParent.Attribute("sql_name").Value;
              string column = ElChild.Attribute("sql_name").Value;

        string req = "declare @ColumnName varchar(100) " + 
                     " declare @TableName varchar(100) " +  
                      " declare @req varchar(max) " +
               "set @ColumnName =" + column + "  set @TableName =" + table +
               "set @req = 'select '+@ColumnName+ ' from '+@TableName+''";

               SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(req, cnSQL);
               SqlDataReader data = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
      }
 }

 // set table name and file xml
readFileXML("tableStudent", file.FileName);
```

Comment: Your code is not complete. Please enclose it an show proper minimal example.

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers in SQL.

Comment: i try to use stored procedure but not working